# Loading a local html file into a webbrowser control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Trying to load a local file into a webbrowser control but this does not seem to work

```
theBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("Assets/info.html", UriKind.Relative));
```

do i have to do a `NavigateToString` instead, and how would i go about doing that?

Comment: `navigate()` supports a string in one of its overloads
i remember it working like this `theBrowser.Navigate("Assets/info.html");` when `"Assets/info.html"` is inside debug folder (or generally in the same folder as the EXE

Comment: I think, it should work the way you're trying. Any exceptions? Did you try `"/Assets/info.html"`?

Comment: yeah i tried with `/` as content and as resource. Ku6popr's solution works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("index.html", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
webBrowser.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

Where index.html saved like Content in your project

Answer (score 2):

Use file:// protocol in your url

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://yourpath/yourfile.html');
```